# How can I install GRUB2 on its own BTRFS subvolume?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, uefi, btrfs

I created a subvolume called `grub`, mounted it as `/boot/grub`, used `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to create a config file and installed it using `grub-install --efi-directory=/root/efi --target=x86_64-efi --recheck /dev/nvme0n1`. After rebooting, it just shows the rescue shell and I have to enter `configfile (hd0,gpt3)/grub/grub.cfg` to get the menu. How can I fix this?

fstab:

```
# /dev/nvme0n1p3 LABEL=ROOT
UUID=3aeda55e-0efa-4917-a78d-f3b8eb6d6113       /               btrfs           rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/root,subvol=root  0 0

# /dev/nvme0n1p1 LABEL=UEFISHELL
UUID=3AB2-A318          /root/efi       vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro       0 2

# /dev/nvme0n1p3 LABEL=ROOT
UUID=3aeda55e-0efa-4917-a78d-f3b8eb6d6113       /boot/grub      btrfs           rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/grub,subvol=grub  0 0

# /dev/nvme0n1p3 LABEL=ROOT
UUID=3aeda55e-0efa-4917-a78d-f3b8eb6d6113       /home           btrfs           rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/home,subvol=home  0 0

# /dev/nvme0n1p3 LABEL=ROOT
UUID=3aeda55e-0efa-4917-a78d-f3b8eb6d6113       /root/btrfs     btrfs           rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/    0 0

# /dev/nvme0n1p3 LABEL=ROOT
UUID=3aeda55e-0efa-4917-a78d-f3b8eb6d6113       /var/cache/pacman/pkg   btrfs           rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=259,subvol=/pkg,subvol=pkg    0 0
```

Comment: Are you mixing up the ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 for UEFI to boot? And Linux /boot partition which must be a Linux type format? The /boot folder or partition has most of grub and kernels. Usually grub not separated from rest of boot files. And those using other formats often use ext4 for /boot to avoid issues, but now grub works with many other formats. Or even have / as ext4 and all data in the other format.

Comment: I have the ESP mounted at /root/efi a btrfs subvolume called /grub mounted at /boot/grub and a btrfs subvolume called /root mounted at /

Comment: Grub starts but it doesn't read the config file

Comment: I have Ubuntu & ESP is mounted at /boot/efi and it has /EFI/ubuntu. So full path is /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu. And in ubuntu folder is grub.cfg which is only three lines an is a configfile to the full grub in my / partition. Check you grub.cfg in your ESP to make sure UUID is correct. example grub.cfg in ESP: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205982/how-make-external-usb-disk-bootable-for-bios-and-uefi UUID must be where full grub.cfg is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the boot directory with `--boot-directory=/boot/`

Comment: As of grub 2.06 this is default behavior `--boot-directory=DIR
              install GRUB images under the directory DIR/grub2 instead of the boot/grub2 directory`